# Installation alongside Windows XP, or dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows

I am new to Linux [environment]. I need to use Ubuntu for some software development. I've created a live USB from the iso image. Is it possible to use it for development purpose?

If not, I need some help with the installation. My system configuration is:

> Intel Core 2 Duo
>   1gb  RAM
>   160 HDD
>   Windows XP SP3

I have two partitions, one for Windows (20GB) and another for data (120GB). I was trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows but i don't want to lose any data.

I downloaded Ubuntu 13.04 from the site and was trying to install it. After selecting the option of "install alongside windows", it's asking to resize the partition. Also it is showing the 20GB Windows partition second to the 120GB partition where I keep the data.

I don't want to lose the XP or any of my data. Also, if you could guide me to where I can get my hands on some of the basic Unix commands, I'll be needing those.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if I understand your question correctly, what you need to do, if you don't want to use your existing XP hard drive, is to add another drive for Ubuntu, or create a persistent USB, and use Ubuntu that way.

A persistent USB will aloow you to run Ubuntu from it, and save any work that you may have.  For help on creating a persistent USB see [Create a Persistent Bootable Ubuntu USB Flash Drive](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/)

Comment: Thank you for the information. I was also wondering will I be able to use it for development purpose? I was trying my hands on hadoop and it'll be very useful if I can develop the programs also.

Comment: I don't see why not.  I recommend using a 16GB USB flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

why not installing along xp ? no problem ! no data are lost !

my way for some years was to install vmware in my xp system and in the vmware then install ubuntu, but this weekend i changed, hostsystem now is the ubuntu and in the vm is a xp because i develop sw for windows-systems

the "realtime" is much better and performance too

but the time i used ubuntu in vmware of xp also was good
to use same data you can make netwok-connection by shared folder

do it !

Answer (score 0):

I am also a very new user and was worried about loosing anything on hard drive.
I bought a new 500gGb drive for laptop, cloned it from original then swapped drives and installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows Vista without any problems.
I wish I had set a larger partition than the default 20Gb though but, as I get more comfortable I'm sure I can just re-size partitions
As I had the Vista OS cloned, I'm keeping original 160Gb drive just in case I need to wipe and start over. So far, no problems

Comment: This is comment, not answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually install Ubuntu to your flash drive as an operating system
instead of as a live CD. By doing that you can plug your flash drive in the 
USB and boot to it and use it as if it were a hard drive.
I have Ubuntu installed on a 64GB flash drive and I keep all my programs,
etcetera on it. 
The really cool part is that I can take my flash drive anywhere,plug it
into any laptop or computer, boot to it and I have my own "PC"  in front of
me!
I even have one desktop that has no hard drives in it, just the DVD+RW.
It works just like a regular desktop when I boot to my flash drive with it!

Comment: Thank you for the info. Just one more thing, the bar on the left side of the home screen shows an option which says 'install ubuntu', I think that means all the components of the OS are not on the USB and I need to install it on the hdd to use it fully, is that correct?

Comment: HiIf you are using the flash drive as a live Cd then it does not

Comment: Hi  If you are using the flash drive as a live CD then it does not really save anything you do and, yes, somethings are not present. The extras and addons that you might want after you install have to be downloaded. The live CD version wold not retain anything you add.    If you install Ubuntu to your flash drive as if it were a hard drive then every change, addition or tweaks will be kept for the next time. The main purpose of live CDs is to let people try out Ubuntu to see if they want to do a permanent install.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late revival, but hopefully you or someone else could find the answer you're looking for in this post. Guaranteed there are several more like it, too!

You could boot up Windows and resize the **data** partition (which likely has a drive letter, like C:/) from there using **disk management** which, if memory serves, is done like this:

```
Open up **Computer Management**
In the console tree, open **Disk Management**
```

Make it, for example, 80 GB so that 40 GB is left for Ubuntu, allowing plenty of room for development and such.

Then, run the live USB you have created, and install Ubuntu to the new, empty 40 GB partition. The **install** option should be on the desktop of your Ubuntu release. There will also be an option in the applications menu which varies depending on which version you are using.

Alternatively, you could create an install disk or USB, which does not run a live environment, and rather brings you straight to the installation menu.